# Using Syscall in Go

Tags: go, system-calls

I am trying to make a very simple script that will pull System uptime and a few other things using system calls in Go. This is some sample code that just will not compile:

```
package main
import "syscall"
func main(){ 
    var info1 = new(syscall.Sysinfo_t) 
    var info2 = syscall.Sysinfo_t{}
}
```

It keeps giving me an error saying `undefined: syscall.Sysinfo_t`. What's wrong?

Comment: Could you actually post the stacktrace? Also, what environment/OS are you running under?

Comment: What OS are you using? `syscall.Sysinfo_t` is only defined for Linux.

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid, thank you. I was trying to use it on OSX. Is there a way to do this on OSX?

Comment: @Bogdan: There's no built-in support for what you're trying to do. You may find this library useful: https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil

Comment: One way would be to run the code under a docker container that either has  Go installed in it so you can run `go run` or build a linux binary that can run on linux and run it in the docker container

Comment: According to Go's [syscall doc](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) this package is "locked down". You can try using `os` which is an interface to the package.

Comment: @TimCooper could you add your comment as an answer?